# Post-processing with VR effect

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, post-processing

I'm working on a web VR project with Three.js (r79) and I'm wondering how can I use the [EffectComposer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js) to add some post-processing in addition to VR effect (one rendering for each eye).

As far as I know, ThreeJS provides 2 example scripts for VR rendering :

- [VREffect](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/effects/VREffect.js)
- [StereoEffect](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/effects/StereoEffect.js)

But none of the 2 seem to manage post-processing effects.